# React - How to update my component when there is a change on the server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I want to reload the page when a put request is successful but it never reloads the page. what is the problem

```
async function saveEdit() {
        await Axios.put('http://localhost:5000/edit', {id: id, newTitle: title, newDescription: description, newImageURL: imageURL});
        window.location.reload();
       
        
    }
```

the request works but the `reload()` line doesn't seem to work. or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Try  `window.location.reload(true);`

Comment: I would also like to add that the best way to update a component when there is a change on the server is to use state and update the state instead of reloading the whole page.

Comment: @JaivBhup still doesn't work? I'm pretty confused

Comment: How can I use, useState to change the component when there is change in the mongodb database

Comment: Try using `window.location.href = window.location.href`

Comment: @JaivBhup maybe the problem is that it's not reaching the reload line? I even tried console logging it and there's no output

Comment: That means that your put request is not sending the response back. And because of that you are stuck at your put request. Check you APIs and send a response back when the edit is done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple implementation of `useState()` hook in react

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  async function saveEdit(id, title, description, imageURL) {
        // Make sure that your request responds back with the relevant and fresh batch of data after the update
        var res = await Axios.put('http://localhost:5000/edit', {id: id, newTitle: title, newDescription: description, newImageURL: imageURL});
        //window.location.href = window.location.href;
        var data = res.data;
        setData(data)
    }
  return (
    <div>
       {data?.map(d=>{
           // How you want to processes your data object.
           return <h1>d.title</h1>
        })}
        <button onClick={()=>saveEdit(1,"Mytitle","description","test Url")}> Update </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For more information in react hooks refer [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).